# MSBuild on Build Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am trying to run vsto project on a build server, the build server downloads code and tries to run it creating a bin directory with files, the issue that I am having is that it is erroring out by giving me an error that the program files x86\msbuild\Microsoft\visualstduio\v10.0\Office tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets cannot be found, I have them on my local machine and I can copy them but I did that before and that solution is incomplete do to the msbuild looking for dlls that I cant seem to find. I searched around and saw that downloading visual studio 2010 design time is neccesary on the build server? How do you download visual studio 2010 design time alone?

Comment: Always start with simply copying the ABC.targets files onto the build server.  See if that works (it does on occasion).  you may try finding the SDK and installing it.  Basically, you start-small and try to get it to work.  The last thing you want to do is install Visual Studio on the build machine (IMHO).

Comment: I eneded up doing that, my issue is when I do that it is asking for dll which I am not trying to install

Comment: I copy over the smallest folder (with those dlls) that I can.  and document it somewhere. (if I had to ever rebuild the build machine)

Comment: I did that and it resolved one issue when building it, but opens up more issues about missing dlls, which I tried adding to the gac which is another issue, think is their a way to have all the neccessities without installing visual studio

Comment: .Net SDK's installs alot.  Example : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: downloading that in now, hopefully I can install the dlls needed for this did it before and gave me onknown operation Build?? from the gacutil